# Hive column casting from decimal to double is resulting in NULL

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I have hive table table1 schema of the table looks like this

```
[CREATE TABLE table1(p_decimal1 DECIMAL(38,5)) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' STORED AS TEXTFILE]
```

and i have below value in the table

```
row  : col(p_decimal1)   
row1 : 12345123451234512345123.45123
```

in later stage 
if i execute

```
select CAST(p_decimal1 AS DOUBLE) from table1;
```

query then I am getting `NULL` as a output.

can you please explain why its coming as NULL ??

Answer (score 0):

DECIMAL is higher level of floating point data type having range of  (approximately -10e308 to 10e308), where double is for normal floating number not for large values.

So in your case you are trying to cast big value in to small data type and that's the reason you a[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BRpTC.png)re getting NULL.

Comment: this is an implicit conversion meaning it is not using cast and hive will do the conversion without using cast. This is different to this SO question.

Answer (score 0):

Casting from decimal to int, double, string and boolean are allowed so you might be hitting a bug. You may report it to hive community si that it will be fixed.

However, I found this hack to convert decimal to double.  Although I have not used/tested it in most of my work, you may use it at your own discretion.

> **select cast(cast(upper(p_decimal1) as string) as double)  from table1;**

result: 1.2345123451234513E22